# fnmatch not working as expected when path contains "\" in PHP

Tags: php, windows

I wonder why the following call returns `false`

```
fnmatch("\\*", "\foo.txt"); //=> false
```

While this one returns `true`

```
fnmatch("/*", "/foo.txt"); //=> true
```

I am using **PHP 7.1** and working on **Windows 7**

Thank you :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php#109389

Comment: @hassan So I can assume that this is a bug not yet solved ?!